# Java - Find shortest path between 2 points in a distance weighted map

Tags: java, path, shortest

I need an algorithm to find shortest path between two points in a map
where road distance is indicated by a number.

what is given:
Start City A
Destination City Z

List of Distances between Cities:

A - B : 10
F - K : 23
R - M : 8
K - O : 40
Z - P : 18
J - K : 25
D - B : 11
M - A : 8
P - R : 15

I thought I could use Dijkstra's algorithm , however it finds shortest distance to all destinations. not just one.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: There's no reason not to use Dijkstra's algorithm here.  It finds the shortest distance between a starting point and all destinations, then you simply select the destination you wanted from the completed list or map of results.

Comment: I think there is a reason not to use Dijkstra in this case. Dijkstra is good to compute the distance from the starting point to all the nodes in the map. If you only want the distance to one point, A* is faster. It's basically the same algorithm expect that A* doesn't expand unwanted nodes. Both Dijkstra and A* can be implemented using a Fibonacci heap (if you care about performance) and will look very similar in the code. Of course you need a heuristic for A*. If you don't have one then Dijkstra is very good indeed.

Comment: I didn't mention the Heuristic method simply because it's not relevant to such a small problem.  If we're looking at how to drive from New York to California, Dijkstra is a poor choice for self evident reasons, but in this case, "There's no reason not to use Dijkstra's algorithm here."

Comment: Yes point taken. For this particular small case it doesn't matter. I wasn't sure if the question only targeted at this specific example or on a more general discussion

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like SplinterReality said: `There's no reason not to use Dijkstra's algorithm here.`

The code below I nicked from [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special:DownloadCode/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29&oldid=15444) and modified it to solve the example in the question.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}


class Edge
{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;
    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
    { target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}

public class Dijkstra
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);

                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
    {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // mark all the vertices 
        Vertex A = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex B = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex D = new Vertex("D");
        Vertex F = new Vertex("F");
        Vertex K = new Vertex("K");
        Vertex J = new Vertex("J");
        Vertex M = new Vertex("M");
        Vertex O = new Vertex("O");
        Vertex P = new Vertex("P");
        Vertex R = new Vertex("R");
        Vertex Z = new Vertex("Z");

        // set the edges and weight
        A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(M, 8) };
        B.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(D, 11) };
        D.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(B, 11) };
        F.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(K, 23) };
        K.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(O, 40) };
        J.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(K, 25) };
        M.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(R, 8) };
        O.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(K, 40) };
        P.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(Z, 18) };
        R.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(P, 15) };
        Z.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(P, 18) };


        computePaths(A); // run Dijkstra
        System.out.println("Distance to " + Z + ": " + Z.minDistance);
        List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(Z);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
    }
}
```

The code above produces:

```
Distance to Z: 49.0
Path: [A, M, R, P, Z]
```

Comment: @luke Any suggestions to find best paths between Multiple Nodes.?

The code returns same path calculated first for each of the Path.

`A -->  Z` 
`Distance to Z: 49.0`
`Path: [A, M, R, P, Z]`

`B -->  Z`
`Distance to Z: 49.0`
`Path: [A, M, R, P, Z]`

Same result for both? I am not sure how. Can you please check?

Comment: vertexQueue.remove(v); should be vertexQueue.remove(u);

Comment: Avoid this. This works quickly but it's hell to modify. Please refer to something decent: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html

Comment: your example is not correct i mean there is no other alternative way of getting from a to z except for `AMRPZ` and i tried your solution and won't work on a graph that is a bit more complicated.

Comment: As @N3sh said 2.5 years ago. Vogella's article is the best. When you try to modify this codebase, you learn many things.

Answer (score 6):

Estimated sanjan:

The idea behind Dijkstra's Algorithm is to explore all the nodes of the graph in an ordered way. The algorithm stores a priority queue where the nodes are ordered according to the cost from the start, and in each iteration of the algorithm the following operations are performed:

1. Extract from the queue the node with the lowest cost from the start, N
2. Obtain its neighbors (N') and their associated cost, which is cost(N) + cost(N, N')
3. Insert in queue the neighbor nodes N', with the priority given by their cost

It's true that the algorithm calculates the cost of the path between the start (A in your case) and all the rest of the nodes, but you can stop the exploration of the algorithm when it reaches the goal (Z in your example). At this point you know the cost between A and Z, and the path connecting them.

I recommend you to use a library which implements this algorithm instead of coding your own. In Java, you might take a look to the [Hipster library](http://hipster4j.org/), which has a very friendly way to generate the graph and start using the search algorithms.

Here you have an example of how to define the graph and start using Dijstra with Hipster.

```
// Create a simple weighted directed graph with Hipster where
// vertices are Strings and edge values are just doubles
HipsterDirectedGraph<String,Double> graph = GraphBuilder.create()
  .connect("A").to("B").withEdge(4d)
  .connect("A").to("C").withEdge(2d)
  .connect("B").to("C").withEdge(5d)
  .connect("B").to("D").withEdge(10d)
  .connect("C").to("E").withEdge(3d)
  .connect("D").to("F").withEdge(11d)
  .connect("E").to("D").withEdge(4d)
  .buildDirectedGraph();

// Create the search problem. For graph problems, just use
// the GraphSearchProblem util class to generate the problem with ease.
SearchProblem p = GraphSearchProblem
  .startingFrom("A")
  .in(graph)
  .takeCostsFromEdges()
  .build();

// Search the shortest path from "A" to "F"
System.out.println(Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search("F"));
```

You only have to substitute the definition of the graph for your own, and then instantiate the algorithm as in the example.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Maintain a list of nodes you can travel to, sorted by the distance from your start node. In the beginning only your start node will be in the list.

While you haven't reached your destination: Visit the node closest to the start node, this will be the first node in your sorted list. When you visit a node, add all its neighboring nodes to your list except the ones you have already visited. Repeat!

Answer (score 3):

This maybe too late but **No one provided a clear explanation of how the algorithm works**

The idea of Dijkstra is simple, let me show this with the following pseudocode.

Dijkstra partitions all nodes into two distinct sets. Unsettled and settled. Initially all nodes are in the unsettled set, e.g. they must be still evaluated.

At first only the source node is put in the set of settledNodes. A specific node will be moved to the settled set if the shortest path from the source to a particular node has been found.

The algorithm runs until the unsettledNodes set is empty. In each iteration it selects the node with the lowest distance to the source node out of the unsettledNodes set. E.g. It reads all edges which are outgoing from the source and evaluates each destination node from these edges which are not yet settled.

If the known distance from the source to this node can be reduced when the selected edge is used, the distance is updated and the node is added to the nodes which need evaluation.

Please note that Dijkstra also determines the pre-successor of each node on its way to the source. I left that out of the pseudo code to simplify it.

*Credits to [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html)*

Answer (score 0):

You can see a complete example using java 8, recursion and streams -> [Dijkstra algorithm with java](http://www.javafragments.com/dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-with-java)