# Android, google maps, polyline, shortest path

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, shortest-path, polyline

I have already read some topics on Stack Overflow but didn't found the exact solution for my problem.
I will try to explain my problem. For example let say that I have a grid 9x9. The coordinates are represented by the junctions.
Is there a method or did someone already implemented a procedure that draw a line from coordinate A (X, Y) to coordinate B (V, W) where the line represents the shortest path..

In my problem I am using Google Maps and I would like to draw a poly-line between coordinates..

This is similar to my problem, but in my case I would like to use coordinates and not "weights"

[Java - Find shortest path between 2 points in a distance weighted map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480022/java-find-shortest-path-between-2-points-in-a-distance-weighted-map)

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using google map then you can use Google Directions API.I hope these links will help you.

http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/