# Find Shortest path in Google map in android

Tags: android

I implement a project that draw path on google map when give source and destination points in android using Google direction Api.But it doesent show the shortest path.how I implement above as show shortest path direction in android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, google maps, polyline, shortest path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663527/android-google-maps-polyline-shortest-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is Duped... see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25664513/3180983

If you are using google map then you can use Google Directions API.I hope these links will help you.

http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/