# how to add delay for distance request in google map api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api to get distance between cities after getting these distance, I want to store them in array. But google api doesnt allow request without delay. How I can add delay. or is there any other way to get driving distance. 
Here is code

```
<?php 
$origin="London";
$destination= array("Manchester","Bristol","glasgow","liverpool");
/* print_r($destination);
$size=sizeof($destination);
echo $size; */
$distance = array("abc");
for($i=0; $i<4;$i++){   
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination[i]&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = utf8_decode($data);
    $obj = json_decode($data);

    //echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text); //km
    //echo($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value); // meters  
    array_push($distance,"$obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text");
}
print_r($distance);
?>
```

above code works fine without loop.

Answer (score 0):

The DirectionsMatrix computes and returns multiple results in a single request. You can place a single request to return all four of those results:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=London&destinations=Manchester|Bristol|glasgow|liverpool&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false

Result:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "Manchester, UK",
      "Bristol, City of Bristol, UK",
      "Glasgow, Glasgow City, UK",
      "Liverpool, Merseyside, UK"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "London, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "336 km",
                  "value" : 335756
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 48 mins",
                  "value" : 13655
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "190 km",
                  "value" : 190196
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 15 mins",
                  "value" : 8094
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "663 km",
                  "value" : 662591
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 34 mins",
                  "value" : 23621
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "354 km",
                  "value" : 354422
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 54 mins",
                  "value" : 14027
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: I know this method.
but problem is after that I have to sort all distance and get the shortest one. and repeate same sequence until I will get the last one.. 
e.g
A->B        
A->C         e.g shortest is C
A->D
A->E

then again but this time origin will change and shortest will not in destinations
C->B
C->D       e.g shortest is E
C->E

Comment: What trouble are you having doing that?

Comment: I just want to create a route map. I have more then 25 destinations. and one origin. What I have to do is to get shortest destination to origin then that destination to next then next neareast. Like greedy approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the code from an algorithm that finds or selects the shortest path in between a point and a set of points (multiple nodes), like in this case. You may follow the strategies describes in the [`Dijkstra's algorithm`](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/programs/graph/Dijkstra-java.html). You can do so by using the comparable interface and comparing the probable set of destinations finding out the shortest one. Doing the same when you choose the shortest one using a look.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480022/java-find-shortest-path-between-2-points-in-a-distance-weighted-map) may help you in understanding what I am trying to say.